# I am trying to setup an upload image button to save an image for each record in an MS Access Database

Tags: database, image, visual-studio-2010, image-uploading

I have researched many sites and Visual Basic books and I have also tried many different code formations. I have built a book form record keeping system in Visual Studio 2010. The form is linked to a MS Access Database. The form works fine, I can update my records, change from record to record, delete items, add new records and save them. The original Database I linked to had several records already (no images)and I have a Field column built into the Database called "BookCover" that I want to populate through the form. I have fields like ISBN, Author etc.

I used the Binding Navigator to perform these functions. 
I am trying to install an upload Book Cover Image button and save the image to the corresponding record and display it on the form. I want the images to change the same as the records do. The button works, the images upload but I cannot save them. I would like the images to upload and be stored in the Database. The Database is named MyBooks and the table name is named Books and the image column is named "BookCover". I only have one table.